# Is all the code in one page ? How webpages work?

Tags: asp.net, razor, code-behind, asp.net-webpages

When using razor syntax in asp.net webpages
On top of the index (or the default or what ever is the start) I can put some razor code that start with @{ }.

I have 2 or 3 classes in another folder, they have some methods that I will need for my web site to work. and here is my questions

**Does all my code for my website go between this bracket in my index page on top of the html tags and from here I call classes and methods but every thing runs here?**

**or  in within this brackets I send variables values to the classes that are in another folder they execute the methods and send back the result to index and then is posted in the html doc?**

example

```
Project X
  Business Class folder
     Class Adding with method Sum()
     Class Grow with method Multiply()
  App Data folder
  Other Folders
  Index.cshtml
  About.cshtml
```

My index file where the app starts

```
    @{ Adding A = new Adding;
        int a=Sum();
        Grow B = new Grow;
        int b=Multiply();
     }
      <html>
       //use of a and b here
      </html>
```

As you can see the code in razor calls classes and methods that are in another folder. 
Question is: **Does the code is executed only here in index?** or **when classes and method are called, the program goes to class Adding or Grow, execute the method and sends back the result to index?**

can you point me to some info or tutorial?**

Comment: Use asp.net mvc for separation

Comment: A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: Guys are some of you so code snob that you can not answer a question of a person whos is learning?

Comment: Why some of you put this on hold and tagged as TOO BROAD when the question is clearly marked in black?

Comment: Hi Mason why the edition? just to know so Ican  follow the rules if any about that

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site works a bit different then your regular forum. It is about clear-cut questions with clear-cut answers. Questions about asking for books, tutorials, learning material, tools etc are not "in scope" for this site. You can find more about this in the [help/on-topic], in [ask] and the [tour]. We don't mind helping beginners, if you show what you tried and where you are stuck (see [mcve]). The way your question is presently worded is too broad, but feel free to [edit] it and have it reopened. PS: I don't think writing in bold helps, as it is considered shouting by many.

Comment: thanks Abel I got, I never meant to shout, I edited my questios and put a small example I am still trying to sediment all this coding stuff in my mind

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call code from outside your .cshtml files then it must be either:

a) in the App_Code folder; or

b) compiled and in the bin folder.

So in your example, your Business Class folder should be inside the App_Code folder.